# Javascript - Check if an array contains only specified values

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I optimize a function that checks if an array contains only specified values not using hardcoded values?

Here is the function

```
function containOnly(value1, value2, array){
  var result;

  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] != value1 && array[i] != value2){
      result = 0;
      break;
    } else
      result = 1;
  }

  if(result === 0)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}

console.log(containOnly(1, 2, [2,1,2]));
```

This function will return true if an array contains specified values. In this function I use if statement to compare two values but how can I use an array of values instead of variables if I want to use more than two values? For example:

```
console.log(containOnly([1, 2, 3], [2,1,2,3,5]));
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using `every` method by passing an `arrow` function as **argument**.

> The [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
>   test implemented by the provided function.

```js
function containsOnly(array1, array2){
  return array2.every(elem => array1.includes(elem))
}
console.log(containsOnly([1, 2, 3], [2,1,2,3,5]));
console.log(containsOnly([1, 2], [2,1,2,1,1]));
```

Another solution is to use `some` method.

```js
function containsOnly(array1, array2){
  return !array2.some(elem => !array1.includes(elem))
}
console.log(containsOnly([1, 2, 3], [2,1,2,3,5]));
console.log(containsOnly([1, 2], [2,1,2,1,1]));
```

Comment: Thank you all for help but I accept this answer because this one is more suitable in terms of javascript and easier for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `&&` up `.includes()` method.

```js
var arr     = [0,1,3,5,7,9,2,6,8,11,32,53,22,37,91,2,42],
    values1 = [0,2,37,42],
    values2 = [91,99,9],
    checker = ([v,...vs], a) => v !== void 0 ? a.includes(v) && checker(vs, a)
                                             : true;
console.log(checker(values1,arr));
console.log(checker(values2,arr));
```

This is also efficient than `.reduce()` since it will stop recursing once the first `false` value is obtained.

Comment: Upvote for your nice solution. I think your method is equivalent of `some` method like in my answer.

Comment: @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut Thanks.. The difference is basically yours should be preferred. In JS recursion with large arrays is problematic... Also this one returns `true` when there is nothing to compare and yours should return `false` though both ways might be desirable.

Answer (score -4):

I haven't actually had any use for JS, but Java translates pretty closely to that. Here's some code that works, but it's not all that efficient:

```
    public boolean containsOnly(int[] findVals, int[] searchArray){
         for(int i=0; i < searchArray.length; i++){
              for(int j=0; j < findVals.length; j++){
                   if(searchArray[i] == findVals[j]){
                        return true;
                   }
              }
         }
         return false;
    }
```

Since this is effectively looping through both arrays twice, it's a relatively slow process, which you may not want if you're running this function a lot in your program.

Otherwise, maybe someone else can figure this out, but you *should* be able to use recursion to solve this. It's very simple if you're just searching for 1 element (quick Google Search should return what you need to do it, at least for Java. Once again, I'm unfamiliar with JS...really should learn it soon)

Here's a *starting point* for some code to try and do this recursively - doesn't work, you get a NullPointerException - someone help on this?

```
    class Searcher{
       public boolean contains(int[] findVals, int[] searchArray){
          int pos = 0;
          while(pos < findVals.length){
          if(searchArray.length==0){
             return false;
          }
          else if(searchArray[0] == findVals[pos]){
             return true;     
          }
          else{
             return contains(findVals, shorten(searchArray));
          }
       }
       return false;
     }

     public int[] shorten(int[] array){
        int[] temp = new int[array.length-1];
        for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
           temp[i] = array[i+1];
        }
        return temp;
     }

     public void main(String[] args){
        int[] findVals = new int[]{1,2,3};
        int[] searchArray = new int[]{2,1,2,3,5};
        System.out.println(contains(findVals, searchArray));
     }
   }
```

Otherwise, there may be yet another way to do this via binarySearch.
(didn't have time to test if this worked or not, but at least the idea is present for you.)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Searcher{
  private int binarySearcher(int[] searchArray, int find){
      int left = 0;
      int mid;
      int right = searchArray.length - 1;
      while(true){
        if(left > right){
          mid = -1;
          break;
        }
        else{
          mid = (left + right) / 2;
          if(find < searchArray[mid]){
            right = mid -1;
          }
          else if(find > searchArray[mid]){
            left = mid + 1;
          }
          else{
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return mid;
    }

  public boolean searchFor(int[] findVals, int[] searchArray){
    Arrays.sort(searchArray);
    Arrays.sort(findVals);
    for(int i=0; i < findVals.length; i++){
      int test = binarySearcher(searchArray, findVals[i]);
      if(test >= 0){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void main(String[] args){
    int[] findVals = new int[]{1,2,3};
    int[] searchArray = new int[]{2,1,2,3,5};
    System.out.println(searchFor(findVals, searchArray));
  }
}
```

Pretty certain that if you could get the recursive call to work, that'd be the most efficient. Next most efficient should be the binary search (if you have large arrays). Lastly, the first method I proposed would be the slowest.

Comment: The OP asked for javascript help. He didn't asked for java help